Object won't show color or material
I'm very new to blender and I was following a YouTube tutorial, specifically by Blender Guru on making a donut. I successfully added color to Suzanne and added in a cone went to change the color. Selected my color and then all of a sudden neither objects showed color. I quit the program and reopened it hoping it would solve my issue and it did not. I'm hoping someone can help me out with this issue.


You are currently in Solid mode (white icon on toolbar). To see colours you need to be in Material Preview or Rendered mode (click the icons to the right of the Solid one or hit Z while the cursor is in the 3D window and select the option from the Piemenu that pops up). That will have been explained in Andrew's tutorial.

